# PowerShell - Removing multiple lines of text between delimiters in a text file

Tags: regex, xml, powershell, replace

I edit XML files and am using PowerShell to open them in Notepad and replace strings of text.  Given two distinct delimiters, a starting and stopping, that appear **multiple times** in an XML file, I would like to completely remove the text between the delimiters (whether the delimiters get removed as well or not does not matter to me).

In the following example text, I want to completely remove the text between my starting and ending delimiter, but keep all the text before and after it.

The issue I am facing is the fact that there are **newlines** at the end of each line of text that prevents me from doing a simple:

```
-replace "<!--A6-->.*?<!--A6 end-->", "KEVIN"
```

Starting Delimiter:

```
<!--A6-->
```

Stopping Delimiter:

```
<!--A6 end-->
```

Example Text:

```
<listItem>
<para>Apple iPhone 6</para>
</listItem>
<listItem>
<para>Apple iPhone 8</para>
</listItem>
<!--A6-->
<listItem>
<para>Apple iPhone X</para>
</listItem>
<!--A6 end-->
</randomList></para>
</levelledPara>
<levelledPara>
<!--A6-->
<title>Available Apple iPhone Colors</title>
<para>The current iPhone model is available in
the follow colors.  You can purchase this model
in store, or online.</para>
<!--A6 end-->
<para>If the color option that you want is out
of stock, you can find them at the following
website link.</para>
```

Current Code:

```
$Directory = "C:\Users\hellokevin\Desktop\PSTest"

$FindBook = "Book"

$ReplaceBook = "Novel"

$FindBike = "Bike"

$ReplaceBike = "Bicycle"

Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Recurse |
    Select-Object -Expand FullName|
        ForEach-Object {
            (Get-Content $_) -replace $FindBook,$ReplaceBook -replace "<!--A6-->.*?<!--A6 end-->", "KEVIN" |
            Set-Content ($_ + "_new.xml")
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Being fairly new to PowerShell, I don't know how to factor in the newlines at the end of each line in my code.  Thanks for looking!

Comment: Do it the most sensible way `<!--A6-->[\S\s]*?<!--A6 end-->`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:

- **Generally, for robust processing, you should use a *dedicated XML parser*** to parse XML text.

  - See [Tomalak's robust, but more complex XML-parsing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162506/45375).
- **In the specific case at hand, using a *regex* is a *convenient shortcut***, with the caveat that it **only works because the blocks of lines being removed are *self-contained elements or element sequences***; if this assumption doesn't hold, the modifications will invalidate the XML document.

  - Additionally, **there may be *character-encoding* issues**, because reading an XML file *as text* doesn't honor an explicit `encoding` attribute potentially present in the file's XML declaration - see the bottom section for details.
  - That said, the technique below is **appropriate for modifying plain-text files** that have no specific formal structure.

---

- You need to **use the `s` (`SingleLine`) [regex option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) to ensure that `.` also matches newlines** - such options, if used inline, must be placed inside `(?...)` at the start of the regex; that is, `'(?s)...'` in this case.

  - Ad hoc, you can alternatively use workaround `[\s\S]` instead of `.`, as suggested by [x15](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12097764/x15); this expression matches any character that is a whitespace char. or a non-whitespace char., and therefore matches *any* char., including newlines.
- To fully remove the lines of interest, you **must also match the preceding and succeeding newline**.

```
(Get-Content -Raw file.xml) -replace '(?s)\r?\n<!--A6-->.*?<!--A6 end-->\r?\n'
```

- `Get-Content -Raw file.xml` reads the file into memory *as a whole* (single string).

  - `Get-Content` makes assumptions about a file's **character encoding** in the absence of a BOM: Windows PowerShell assumes ANSI encoding, and PowerShell [Core] v6+ now sensibly assumes UTF-8. Since `Get-Content` is a general-purpose text-file reading cmdlet, it is *not* aware of a potential `encoding` attribute in the XML declaration of XML input files (e.g., 
    `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`)
  - Similarly, `Set-Content` defaults to ANSI in Windows PowerShell, and BOM-less UTF-8 PowerShell [Core] v6+.
  - When in doubt, use the `-Encoding` parameter, both with `Get-Content` and `Set-Content`
  - See bottom section for more information.
- `\r?\n` matches both Windows-style CRLF newlines and Unix-style LF-only ones.
- Use `(?:\r?\n)?` instead of `\r?\n` if newlines aren't guaranteed to precede / succeed the lines of interest.

To verify that the resulting string is still a valid XML document, simply cast the command (or its captured result) to `[xml]`: `[xml] ((Get-Content ...) -replace ...)`

If you find that the document is broken, use [Tomalak's fully robust, but more complex XML-parsing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59162506/45375).

---

#### XML files and character encodings:

If you use `Get-Content` to read an XML file *as text*, and that file has neither a UTF-8 BOM nor a UTF-16 / UTF-32 BOM, `Get-Content` makes an *assumption*: it assumes ANSI encoding (e.g., Windows-1252) in Windows PowerShell, and, more sensibly, UTF-8 encoding in PowerShell [Core] v6+. Since **`Get-Content` is a general-purpose text-file reading cmdlet, it is *not* aware of a potential `encoding` attribute in the XML declaration of XML input files**.

- If you know the actual encoding, use the `-Encoding` parameter to specify it.
- Use `-Encoding` with the same value for saving the file with `Set-Content` later: As is generally the case in PowerShell, once data has been loaded into memory by a file-reading cmdlet, *no information about its original encoding is retained*, and using a file-writing cmdlet such as `Set-Content` later uses *its fixed default encoding*, which again, is ANSI in Windows PowerShell, and BOM-less UTF-8 in PowerShell [Core] v6+. Note that, unfortunately, different cmdlets have different defaults in Windows PowerShell, whereas PowerShell [Core] v6+ commendably consistently defaults to UTF-8.

The [`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument) .NET type (whose PowerShell type accelerator is `[xml]`) offers **robust XML parsing**, and using its `.Load()` and `.Save()` methods provide **better encoding support *if* the document's XML declaration contains an explicit `encoding` attribute** naming the encoding used:

- If such an attribute is present (e.g., `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>`), both `.Load()` and `.Save()` will honor it.

  - That is an input file with an `encoding` attribute will be read correctly, and saved with that same encoding.
  - Of course, this assumes that the encoding named in the `encoding` attribute reflect's the input file's *actual* encoding.
- Otherwise, *if the file has no BOM*, (BOM-less) UTF-8 is *assumed*, as with PowerShell [Core] v6+'s `Get-Content` / `Set-Content` - that is sensible, because an XML document that has neither an `encoding` attribute nor a UTF-8 or UTF-16 BOM should default to UTF-8, per the [W3C XML Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charencoding); if the file *does* have a BOM, only UTF-8 and UTF-16 are permitted *without also naming the encoding in an `encoding` attribute*, although in practice `XmlDocument` also reads UTF-32 files with a BOM correctly.

  - This means that `.Save()` will *not* preserve the encoding of a (with-BOM) UTF-16 or UTF-32 file *that doesn't have an `encoding` attribute*, and will instead create a BOM-less UTF-8 file.
  - If you want to *detect* a file's actual encoding - as either inferred from its BOM / absence thereof or, if present, the `encoding` attribute, read your file via an `XmlTextReader` instance:

    ```
    # Create an XML reader.
    $xmlReader = [System.Xml.XmlTextReader]::new(
      "$pwd/some.xml" # IMPORTANT: use a FULL PATH
    )

    # Read past the declaration, which detects the encoding,
    # whether via the presence / absence of a BOM or an explicit
    # `encoding` attribute.
    $null = $xmlReader.MoveToContent()

    # Report the detected encoding.
    $xmlReader.Encoding

    # You can now pass the reader to .Load(), if needed
    # See next section for how to *save* with the detected encoding.
    $xmlDoc = [xml]::new()
    $xmlDoc.Load($xmlReader)
    $xmlReader.Close()
    ```
  - If a given file is *non-compliant* and you know the actual encoding used and/or you want to *save with a given encoding* (be sure that it doesn't contradict the `encoding` attribute, if there is one), you can specify encodings explicitly (the equivalent of using `-Encoding` with `Get-Content` / `Set-Content`), use the `.Load()` / `.Save()` method overloads that accepts a `Stream` instance, via `StreamReader` / `StreamWriter` instances constructed with a given encoding; e.g.:

    ```
    # Get the encoding to use, matching the input file's.
    # E.g., if the input file is ISO-8859-1-encoded, but lacks
    # an `encoding` attribute in the XML declaration.
    $enc = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding('ISO-8859-1')

    # Create a System.Xml.XmlDocument instance.
    $xmlDoc = [xml]::new()
    # Create a stream reader for the input XML file
    # with explicit encoding.
    $streamIn = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new(
      "$pwd/some.xml", # IMPORTANT: use a FULL PATH
      $enc
    )
    # Read and parse the file.
    $xmlDoc.Load($streamIn)
    # Close the stream
    $streamIn.Close()

    # ... process the XML DOM.

    # Create a stream *writer* for saving back to the file
    # with the same encoding.
    $streamOut = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new(
      "$pwd/t.xml", # IMPORTANT: use a FULL PATH
      $false, # don't append
      $enc    # same encoding as above in this case.
    )

    # Save the XML DOM to the file.
    $xmlDoc.Save($streamOut)
    # Close the stream
    $streamOut.Close()
    ```

A **general caveat re passing file paths to .NET methods: Always use *full paths***, because .NET's idea of the current directory typically differs from PowerShell's.

Comment: The encoding, if not defined in the XML declaration, is assumed to be UTF-8, all other cases require an XML declaration, which is something the XML serializer will know. That's the elegance of it, the encoding problem is abstracted away *completely* if you"re using XML parsers to interact with serialized XML. Every parser can read any ancoding and will configure itself transparently for it. People taking "convenience" shortcuts are the ones introducing issues. I'm sorry for being such a PITA but seing this being done wrong all over the place grinds my gears. ;)

Comment: Wow, that's quite the substantial addition. There's a certain irony in how many disclaimers and warnings and how much additional explanation and code is necessary in the end to manually work around the fully solved problem of dealing with XML file encodings. (And there is a certain irony to the fact that the OP accepted this answer because they are set on using the worst-possible way of dealing with XML - regex - and don't know enough about neither regex *nor* XML to understand the implications of any of this.)

Comment: @Tomalak: The addition is also of interest to people who _do_ want to use the XML API. There's certainly enough warnings and enough information in the answer to make an _informed decision_ as to whether you want to take the shortcut or not, and for users who come here due to the generic title ("in text files"), the approach is appropriate. In short: the answer is framed as: You may not want to do this, because the approach is brittle, but here's how to do it, if you know what you're doing. I've removed my previous comments, because I feel the answer tells the full story now (and, btw, +1).

Answer (score 1):

Using search-and-replace on XML files is **extremely** inadvisable and should be avoided at all costs, because it's way too easy to damage the XML this way.

There are better ways of modifying XML, and they all follow this schema:

- load the XML document
- modify the document tree
- write the XML document back to file.

For your case ("remove nodes between markers") this could be as follows:

- load the XML document
- look at all XML nodes, in document order
- when we see a comment that reads "A6", set a flag to remove nodes from now on
- when we see a comment that reads "A6 end", unset that flag
- collect all nodes that should be removed (that come up while the flag is on)
- in a last step, remove them
- write the XML document back to file.

The following program would do exactly this (and also remove the "A6" comments themselves):

```
$doc = New-Object xml
$doc.Load("C:\path\to\your.xml")

$toRemove = @()
$A6flag = $false
foreach ($node in $doc.SelectNodes('//node()')) {
    if ($node.NodeType -eq "Comment") {
        if ($node.Value -eq 'A6') {
            $A6flag = $true
            $toRemove += $node
        } elseif ($node.Value -eq 'A6 end') {
            $A6flag = $false
            $toRemove += $node
        }
    } elseif ($A6flag) {
        $toRemove += $node
    }
}
foreach ($node in $toRemove) {
    [void]$node.ParentNode.RemoveChild($node)
}

$doc.Save("C:\path\to\your_modified.xml")
```

You could do string replacement inside the `foreach` loop as well:

```
if ($node.NodeType -eq "Text") {
    $node.Value = $node.Value -replace "Apple","APPLE"
}
```

Doing `-replace` on a single `$node.Value` is safe. Doing `-replace` on the entire XML is not.

Comment: Its unlikely `<!--A6-->` or `<!--A6 end-->` will be inside a CDATA block or a hidden content section, and doesn't make sense it's inside another comment fragment. Given that, the regex way is faster.

Comment: Interesting.  I was not aware that XML documents were that volatile where simple text removals could cause that big of issues.  I will take some time to study your program to understand it.  Thanks Tomalek.

Comment: They are. Treating XML files as if they were merely plain text will get you into trouble very quickly outside of hand-crafted lab scenarios. XML documents are tree structures, the rules they have to follow are numerous and complex. The only sane option is to load the tree, modify it, and save it to file again. Every other approach will blow up sooner or later.